# How can I tell if my email has been sent?

Tags: android, email, android-intent

I'm using the following code to send an email in my app.

```
public void sendEmail() {
    emailSent = 1;
    String to = toEmail.getText().toString();
    String subject = getUser() + " - User Feedback";
    String message = bodyTxt;

    Intent email = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] { to });
    email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
    email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message);

    email.setType("message/rfc822");
    try {
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(email, "Send Email..."));
    } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
        String msg = ex.getMessage().toString();
        emailSent = 2;
        Toast.makeText(this, "There was a problem sending this email, please try again.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } 
}
```

The email.setType() presents a screen offering options for which method to send the message including email. This works fine if the user selects email as a copy of the email comes up and the user can then send it. However, if the user doesn't do anything and simply uses the back space it returns to the app and assumes the email has been sent. How can I test for the user not sending the email?

Comment: With `Intent` you can not . Implicit intent does not return any result .

Comment: You can query SMTP server for the response. You should probably do it in any case to check if mail was delivered when it "leaves" the sending device.

Comment: That sounds more positive, I'll give that a try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could `startActivityForResult()` and listen for a `RESULT_OK` in `onActivityResults`. But there is no framework requirement that forces the email app to [setResult](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setResult(int)) appropriately. So your mileage may vary based on the email client app.